# SQLite database connection is making changes in memory but not saving to the file - AS3 AIR

Tags: database, sqlite, file-io, air, dao

I'm trying to write to a local SQLite database using the `flash.data.*` classes in AIR. I'm opening a synchronous connection in `CREATE` mode and using the `begin()` and `commit()` methods to execute the queries. Everything seems to be executing as expected. The query `execute()` and connection `commit()` method's success handler is being called, the connection object's `totalChanges` property is being incremented, everything looks good except **the database file is not being written to**. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

I don't think it's related to...

- the query itself since that was
  throwing errors whenever something
  didn't match up.
- the file mode for the same reason.
- file permissions - currently set to 777

Simplified version of the code:

```
var database:File = new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath + "//" + PATH_TO_DB );
var connection:SQLConnection = new SQLConnection();
connection.open( database, SQLMode.CREATE );
connection.begin();

var statement:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
statement.sqlConnection = connection;
statement.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, onQueryResult);
statement.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, onQueryError);

statement.text = "INSERT INTO myCrazyTable (foo) VALUES ('bar')";
statement.execute();
connection.commit(new Responder(onCommitComplete));

function onQueryResult(event:SQLEvent):void {
    trace("Query successful"); // this is getting called
}

function onQueryError(event:SQLErrorEvent):void {
    trace("Error in query: " + event.error.message);
}   

function onCommitComplete(event:SQLEvent):void {
    trace("Commit Success"); // this is getting called
    connection.close();
}

// Database isn't getting touched.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I ended up rewriting the code for accessing the database. I'm not sure exactly where the problem was, something I must have been overlooking. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check options defined by pragma? For example http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous can cause this behavior.

Comment: I have PRAGMA synchronous set to FULL (I also tried NORMAL). Still seeing this behaviour. Do you know of any other settings that might cause this?

Comment: I think any other PRAGMA option does not affect it. Both FULL and NORMAL are ok, I think.

Comment: I am not a AIR expert, but maybe the mistake is somewhere else. I think the _connection.commit()_ statement should be placed after _statement.execute()_. Else you close the connection before the insert is executed.

Comment: You're right. I'll fix that. That's not the issue in my working code, I just wrote the example sloppily.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would ask is, how do you know it isn't being touched?  Timestamp?  Or are you querying for the item and not finding it?

The main reason I ask is, I'm suspicious of this code:

`var database:File = new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath + "//" + PATH_TO_DB );`

I think the // is incorrect, and I think possibly your DB is ending up somewhere other than where you think it is, most likely at the root filesystem.  If my theory is correct, you are writing data to a different db than you think you are, not just "in memory".

Comment: Hey Dan, Good point. This was one of the first things I checked. The file is resolving to the correct location on the hard drive.

Comment: You accepted this as the "correct answer".  Did you find that this was the issue, or what?

Comment: No. But it was a good suggestion. I guess my own answer was the correct one.